# Container-independent custom realm (e.g. for Tomcat and Jetty)

Tags: java, tomcat, authorization, jetty

I want to wire the already existing database user authentication of my website with the authentication mechanisms of e.g. Tomcat AND Jetty. The purpose is to protect access some JSP's in the "admin" area using the users in the database.
As far as I can see, the Java interfaces for authentication are not standartised, only the XML configuration(?).

That means that if I would use an authentication implementation (e.g. `JDBCRealm` or a custom `RealmBase`) for Tomcat, I won't be able to run my web application on Jetty anymore.

How can I solve that problem? Does anyone know e.g. a good framework as an abstraction layer?

Comment: JAAS and JASPI are supposed to provide this, as a standard, but they are still viewed as rather recent standards and are just now starting to hit their stride with implementations on both Jetty and Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks :) How is it different from the Spring stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Spring Security](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security) for this, and still be able to run the application in either Tomcat or Jetty.

Spring Security allows you to specify which pages to protect, forcing the user to login. It then allows you to write a custom login method which actually can do whatever you want. In your case this would be accessing the database to authenticate the user.

I would recommend Spring since it is really popular, and in your case would run on both Tomcat and Jetty (or another application server).

For more details on how to implement this I would recommend the documentation (see link) or one of the many tutorials out there.